# How to change font in realtime in Unity?

Tags: c#, fonts, unity-game-engine

I tried to change the font by the C# script in the real time. it changed in the inspector but the text mesh looks like blended.
When I pause and change to another font and return to the desired one it looks fine.

So how do I fix this issue ?
is it a bug ?

**EDIT**
Here is my code:

```
public TextMesh text;

void Awake()
{
     en_font = Resources.Load<Font>(“font Name”);
     text.font = en_font;
}
```

Comment: can you show some code ?

Answer (score 7):

Try This Code :

```
Font ArialFont = (Font)Resources.GetBuiltinResource (typeof(Font), "Arial.ttf");
textMesh.font = ArialFont;
textMesh.renderer.sharedMaterial = ArialFont.material;
```

Comment: I Get this :(

The resource Arial.ttf could not be loaded from the resource file!
UnityEngine.Resources:GetBuiltinResource(Type, String)
GameControlScript:Start() (at Assets/Scripts/GameControlScript.cs:29)

Comment: make sure that your file is in the correct path and you use the same name